# Is it possible to add a shortcut key for a context command?

Tags: pantheon-files, files

Can I add a shortcut key for context commands (right-click commands)?

For example, I want to add a shortcut key for `Open In --> Terminal` in the Files application. Can I, perhaps, add a shortcut to a `.contract` entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files (like other elementary apps) does not implement customisable shortcuts. The only customisable shortcuts available are those in the Switchboard keyboard plug. So you could set up a custom shortcut to open terminal at a fixed location using the command `io.elementary.terminal -w <full-path-to-directory>`, but implementing a shortcut to open the current directory in Terminal would require significant changes to Files code.  Requests for changes to Files should be made at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues for consideration.